# Arduino UNO only works with Monitor Serial opened

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, serial-data

My Arduino Uno will not work without the Serial Monitor opened. I have a PHP script to send data to the board. When I send the data, the `TX` and `L` LEDs light up, but the action is not executed. It is only executed when the Serial Monitor is opened. Can you please help me?

Code in Arduino:

```
int const RED = 2;

int status = 0, temp =0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(RED, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  if(Serial.available() > 0) {
    temp = Serial.read();
    if(temp != -1)
      status = temp - '0';

    Serial.print("status: ");
    Serial.println(status);

    if(status == 1)
      digitalWrite(RED, HIGH);
    else
      digitalWrite(RED, LOW);

    delay(1000);
  }

}
```

PHP script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Alarme</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="alarme" value="ON">
        </form>

        <form action="#" method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="alarme" value="OFF">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php

$port = fopen("/dev/ttyUSB0", "w");
fwrite($port, ($_POST['alarme'] == 'ON') ? 1 : 0);
fclose($port);
```

My circuit is simple, it only consists of one LED and a 220 ohm resistor.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Arduino SE! I'm going to close this question because it lacks a clear example of the problem (code and any applicable circuit) that we need to help you fix your issue. Once you have a clear, minimal example of the problem's code and wiring, feel free to edit your question and it may be reopened. Thanks!

Comment: @AnonymousPenguin I added details

Comment: On many (most ?) systems, you can't open the port and immediately write to it, as that will result in a time consuming auto-reset.  You need to hold the port open and configured in general, and write when you need something.

Comment: I fixed, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the auto-reset of the Arduino, I disabled it.

To disable, I connected a 10uf capacitor on the GND and RES. As in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Interesting!  I have a few sketches I remember have failed until I open the Serial Monitor.  I had a heck of a time with one writing between a rpi and a bluno nano, so Ill go check that out later.  But more recently, I have a sketch that writes data from the bluno nano to an iOS app and sometimes Ill plug in the bluno nano to a usb battery and open up the iOS app BlunoTerminal and Ill get (null) (null) (null)...I plug the bluno nano into the laptop and check BlunoTerminal and still (null) (null) (null)...but I open up the Serial Monitor and voila, values start pouring in!

Comment: Signed in to thank you very much. After tons of frustration this made my day! Had the same problem as described, and diagnosing it was incredibly hard.